# view does not rotate when orientation is upsidesidedown in ios 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation

I tring to make app support all orientation. Its  working fine but only upside down orientation is not working. I am using ios7. For upside down the view does not rotate. I tried following code

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate  
{
return yes;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; // etc
}
```

My only second method is called but not first method. In infoPlist I enabled all the supported orientations.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to support all orientation. If I set shouldAutorotate to NO the my view will not rotate. I am only facing problem when my device home button is upside, in the case the whole view should also get orientate to accordingly but it is not.

Answer (score 5):

Found the fix. Sourced mainly from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12758715/394969

In a nutshell for people who land here first:

```
/* In your view controller */
// Add support for upside down 
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Also flip on all device orientations in project settings as outlined in @Jignesh Mayani's answer. If that doesn't immediatley fix your issue check the link above for how to work with nav controllers and tab controllers (they all must support the required interface orientations).

Comment: You need this even if you have Upside Down checked in your project settings. It seems like the default for Apple is to ignore the upside down setting.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you have check, Go your project setting and Check [image]