# How to get an iOS 7 iPhone app to rotate to all interface orientations?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm working on an iPhone app. Right now all my view controllers rotate to portrait, landscape left, and landscape right (default behavior for an iPhone app out of the box). What I want is for my app's setup, app-wide, to include support for all interface orientations. *How do I make that happen?* I have all interface orientations selected at the project level and it's not making any difference. Here's a pic: [image]

Now, when I test my app on my iPhone, it refuses to rotate to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`. *Why?*

Okay, once we get that figured out, there is a follow up question... I have a single view controller within my app that I only want to support `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` and `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` how can I achieve this? I have the following code in my controller and it doesn't do the trick:

```
// The following method never gets called (but wanted to
// include this to show that I've tried it).
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

// This method does get called but has no effect. The VC that this method
// belongs to rotates to all interface orientations except for
// UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown which is definitely
// not what I want...
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}

// This method never gets called either and therefore has no effect...
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Note that my app is storyboard based (if that makes any difference). Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`

Comment: @Kevin where should I put `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`?

Comment: `supportedInterfaceOrientations`

Comment: @Kevin Thx for the suggestion. However, it did not work. I want my entire app to be able to render in upside down portrait mode. When I added your suggestion to a specific controller via `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, that specific controller still did not rotate to upside down portrait.

Comment: Answer: [How to get an iOS 7 iPhone app to rotate to all interface orientations][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542472/why-iphone-5-doesnt-rotate-to-upsidedown/12758715#12758715

Answer (score 0):

By doing what is explained in [Landscape Mode ONLY for iPhone or iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647786/landscape-mode-only-for-iphone-or-ipad/11548934#11548934) and adding evey interface orientation when doing it, it will support all orientations.

Change your App's `Info.plist` file:

Add `Supported interface orientations` row to your App's `Info.plist` file with all the supported interface orientation's

[image: row's]

Add the supported interface orientation's to "Supported Interface Orientations". 
(`Targets -> YourApp -> Supported Interface Orientations -> Landscape Left & Right`)

[image: Supported Interface Orientations]

Comment: I just created a brand new iPhone project in Xcode. Here's my `Info.plist`:

    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>

In app's single view controller, I added:

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
    {
        return YES;
    }

It still won't rotate to upside down portrait orientation. What am I missing?